# Add prefix with text taken from other column when entering data in Excel

Tags: excel

I am new in using excel and I have a problem here.
I want Excel to automatically prefix some text whenever I enter data in a column. The text to be prefix has to be taken from another cell in the same row but from other column.

I have looked at the custom format cells features but seems like it can only let you prefix your data with a predetermine word.
Is there any other way to achieve this? 
In case it matters, I'm using Excel 2013.

Comment: If you want Excel to prefix it in the same cell, you'll need VBA. If you are okay with prefixing the value in an adjacent column, you can use a function. If that text is a number, you can use custom format (but the final value will only be an aesthetic change, not a change in the value itself).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And yes, I would like the prefix to be added in the same cell whenever I key in the data. Other than using VBA, is there still other work around?

Comment: No, unless you enter formulas in each cell...

Comment: which column would you like to use as a prefix (if you consider a vba solution)

Comment: An adjacent column. Say I enter data in a cell from columnB, I want the data to be prefix with text grab from a cell in the same row from columnA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments I see your okay with a third cell representing the final result.  Assuming prefix is in column A, entry data is in column B, and result is a formula in column C like the following:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,B1)
```

Result:

[image]

---

If you change your mind about a vba solution, you can setup a worksheet change macro like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  If Target.Column = 2 Then
    If IsEmpty(Target.Value) = False Then
       Target.Value = Target.Offset(0, -1).Value + Target.Value
    End If
  End If
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This routine will function on any cell changed in column 'B' and prefix the value in column 'A' unless it's blank (i.e. you erased data)

Again I'm assuming prefix is in column A and data entry is in column B but with the result this time being in column B.

This routine must be in the sheet your using, not in a generic module

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much. Your VBA example is very helpful. Save me time from having to learn something which I rarely use.